# After selecting CSM in BIOS my computer doesn't start correctly

Tags: windows-10, boot, bios, asus-laptop

First I had the problem with my laptop that it started to BIOS, not to Windwos. When I wanted to select a boot device, there weren't any to choose from.

After I read [this](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-2003382/computer-boot-bios.html) I enabled CSM. After enabling CSM I get this when I start the computer:

[image: photo of the screen].

When I restart the computer I get the same thing. I don't know what should I do.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is not the first time you have used your laptop, it may be a corrupted drive that can not be read.

Source:
http://www.tomsguide.com/answers/id-2838421/open-laptop-turn-reboot-select-proper-boot-device-press-key.html

You may want to try the installation disc or inserting a bootable drive. You can actually create bootable drives from USB drives as well:

https://mspoweruser.com/how-to-create-a-bootable-usb-drive-for-windows-10/

Hope any of this helps.

-SirPuddles

Comment: Okay. Now I can get to BIOS. But I when I try to boot SeaTools on my USB stick (my DVD dive doesn't work) it doesn't work. Is there another similar program that can boot on USB?